# How Store and Retrieve data in Android App Development

Tags: java, android, sql, xml, mobile

I was wondering if anyone knows how to store series of data in an android app, and also how to call those data back (like a bible app or Hymnal).
Is it XML or a form of SQL?

Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to store/retrieve a small data (some variables) you can use sharedPrefrences and [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html) is an example,but if you are going to store/retrieve big data you can use database SQLiteOpenHelper  [example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html).